# onMessageReceived don't call when send only data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications

I'm trying to save Firebase notification into the Room Dao when app in the background. Send notification with Postman, but onMessage received called only when app is foreground and message have `notification : {}` body. Can any help me with this problem please :3

My FirebaseMessagingService implementation :

```
class NotificationService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage) {

    val title = p0.notification?.title ?: return
    val message = p0.notification?.body ?: return
    Log.e("TAG","Notification: $title: $message")

    Log.e("TAG","Data from notification : ${p0.data["key_1"]}")

    Log.e("TAG","MessageReceived")
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        NotificationApp.db?.notificationDao()?.setNotification(Notification(data = p0.data["key_1"]))
    }

    showNotification(p0)
}

fun showNotification(data: RemoteMessage) {
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_input_get)
        .setContentTitle(data.notification?.title)
        .setContentText(data.notification?.body)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

    val manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "test_notification_channel_id", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
    manager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build())
}
```

Manifest :

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/notification_main_chanel_id" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".NotificationService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/notification_main_chanel_id" />
```

And notification example in Postman :

```
   {
  "data": {
    "title": "I'd tell you a chemistry joke",
    "message": "but I know I wouldn't get a reaction",
    "image-url":
      "https://docs.centroida.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/notification.png",
    "key_1" : "Heh message"
  },
  "to": "DEVICE_TOKEN",
  "priority": "high"
}
```

Comment: I found the solution. The problem will be in these rows `val title = p0.notification?.title ?: return
    val message = p0.notification?.body ?: return`